# syntax error, unexpected T_STATIC

Tags: php, late-static-binding

I have this error while trying to use late static bindings. All I can find in google about this error is that people didn't have PHP5.3, but I have version 5.3.6.

Could someone help me please ?

Thanks

```
class Media
{
    private $nom,
            $ext;

    public function ext_autorisees() { return array(); }

    public function __construct( $fichier, $thumb = false )
    {
        $fichier = explode( ".", $fichier );

        $nom = $fichier[0];
        $ext = $fichier[1];

        if( in_array( strtoupper( $ext ), static::ext_autorisees() ) )
        {
            if( strpos( $nom, "thumb_" ) === 0 && !$thumb )
                throw new Exception("");
        }
        else
            throw new Exception("");

        $this->nom = $nom;
        $this->ext = $ext;
    }

    public function getNom() { return $this->nom; }
    public function getExt() { return $this->ext; }
    public function getPath() { return $this->getNom() . "." . $this->getExt(); }
    public function getThumb() { return "thumb_" . $this->getPath(); }

}
```

Comment: This runs just fine for me.  What line is the error on?  How do you know you're running 5.3?

Comment: Because I installed it myself...

Comment: Well, curiously, my directory is named PHP5.3.6 , but when I call phpinfo() it tells me PHP 5.2 ...

Answer (score 1):

there is a problem in static::ext_autorisees()

Comment: you can use a self::ext_autorisees()

Comment: No, I have other class that extends that one, and I want their ext_autorisees() to be called, not this one...